# Detect Advertisement Group in Video

Tags: video

If I'm running an internet streaming service, and I want to be able to "cut" the broadcast when an ads group is coming, how can I achieve this?

I understand there is something called "cue tones", but I didn't find helpful resource to read from.

It would be great to have some kind of tutorial/example or a code snippet to learn more about the detection of those tunes.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where you want to do this.

*Cue-tone* is a basic audio burst tools.( Though there are more advanced methods now). This is generated by original play out server when a new event starts - as configured. There is no distinction between a commercial or non-commercial transmission though. But this tones are embedded to achieve something on the path.

Usually, the video which at homes these cue-tones/or such triggers won't come till your set-top-box and of no use to you when video is off line. This is a tool used by broadcasters to manage certain things in down time; and most often they *DON'T* want user's to remove the Ad's so it wont work to you.

To my knowledge there *is* no tool that allow you do to this for end users. There can be means to achieve this, if you have access to systems of broadcaster's play outs.